# Base SDK of 6.0.1 is not an option in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, base-sdk

I am trying to set the base SDK of my project in Xcode to 6.0.1, however it is telling me that 6.0 is the latest version. I have the latest version of Xcode (4.5.2), so am I missing something? Can anybody tell me if their Xcode has an option of 6.0.1 as their base SDK? The reason I ask is because I received a crash report after trying to submit an app to Apple and they had tested it on devices runnning ios 6.0.1. If anyone could help that would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure to get in the habit of only doing layout and flow testing using the simulator.  All serious testing (especially for bugs and memory usage, etc) should always be done on a device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that the simulator is updated for minor versions.  You will need to run the app on a device that is running 6.0.1.  Xcode 4.5.2 is the latest production release and comes with the 6.0 SDK.  Xcode 4.6 Beta 4 is the latest developer release and comes with 6.1 SDK.

Bottom line is that you can't test against 6.0.1 in the simulator, you need to test on a device with 6.0.1 installed.

To test this just `NSLog` this:

```
NSLog(@"iOSVersion = %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Xcode 4.6 Developer Preview. It is available on https://developer.apple.com/xcode/